# is there a touch that can create parent directories like mkdir -p?

Tags: linux, bash, touch, zsh, mkdir

I have the following two functions defined in my .zshrc

```
   newdir(){ # make a new dir and cd into it
        if [ $# != 1 ]; then
            printf "\nUsage: newdir <dir> \n"
        else
            /bin/mkdir -p $1 && cd $1 
        fi
    }
    
    newfile() { # make a new file, open it for editing, here specified where
        if [ -z "$1" ]; then
            printf "\nUsage: newfile FILENAME \n" 
            printf "touches a new file in the current working directory and opens with nano to edit \n\n"
            printf "Alternate usage: newfile /path/to/file FILENAME \n"
            printf "touches a new file in the specified directory, creating the diretory if needed, and opens to edit with nano \n"
        elif [ -n "$2" ]; then
            FILENAME="$2"
            DIRNAME="$1"
            if [ -d "$DIRNAME" ]; then
                cd $DIRNAME    
            else
                newdir $DIRNAME
            fi
        else
            FILENAME="$1"
        fi
    
    touch ./"$FILENAME"
    nano ./"$FILENAME"
    }
```

but I am wondering, is there a version of touch that acts similar to mkdir -p, in that it can create parent dirs as needed in one line/command?

Comment: Why not use `mkdir -p`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't understand your question. function newdir calls mkdir -p.  if the conditions are met, function  newfile calls function newdir, which calls mkdir -p.

Comment: You asked for something similar to `mkdir -p` so I was just wondering why use something similar instead of `mkdir -p` (like Léa Gris showed below)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no touch that can create parent directory path, so write your own in standard POSIX-shell grammar that also works with zsh:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

touchp() {
  for arg
  do
    # Get base directory
    baseDir=${arg%/*}

    # If whole path is not equal to the baseDire (sole element)
    # AND baseDir is not a directory (or does not exist)
    if ! { [ "$arg" = "$baseDir" ] || [ -d "$baseDir" ];}; then
      # Creates leading directories
      mkdir -p "${arg%/*}"
    fi

    # Touch file in-place without cd into dir
    touch "$arg"
  done
}
```

Comment: can you explain how ${arg##*/} and ${arg%/*} work?  This looks like something I would like to integrate into my scripts but google doesn't seem to like either combination of special chars to learn more on my own.  Thanks.

Comment: @cheechi see variable expansion in shell

Comment: I was having difficulty understanding how the shell explands it, and the shell expansion that i usually reference didn't dumb it down enough for me so 

$ for arg in $(echo /path/to/file) ; do echo "${arg%/*}" ; done 
/path/to

I get THAT it works, but i will continue reading up on why it works as I was expecting it to echo only 'to' in this example.(pardon the apparent lack of formatting in comments)

Comment: @cheechi In this example, the `/*` matches "/file" at the end of the variable's value, so that's removed leaving "/path/to". BTW, `$(echo /path/to/file)` is just an overcomplex and error-prone way to write `/path/to/file` -- the `$( )` and `echo` basically cancel each other out. Also, `for arg in /path/to/file` is an overcomplex way of doing `arg=/path/to/file` (since there's only one value, the loop isn't needed).

Comment: @GordonDavisson I apprciate this. i was trying to make as similar, and as simple, a reproduction of the presented for loop so that i could understand visually what the wildcard expansion was doing. the loop was to try to understand the touchp() in as complete a way as i could, with a one liner.

Comment: for all this i could also do

`touchp() { # touch a file with mkdir -p functionality, create parent path if needed
if [ -n $(echo "$arg" | grep "/") ]; then
  # Creates leading directories if not exists
    mkdir -p "${arg%/*}"
fi

touch "$arg"

}`

unless i am missing something, right?

Comment: @cheechi not needed.

Comment: @GordonDavisson `the loop isn't needed`, Indeed the sole purpose of the loop is here to be able to process multiple touched paths passed as arguments to the function.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh` you can do:

```
mkdir -p -- $@:h && : >>| $@
```

`mkdir` is given the "head" of each argument to make the directories (`man zshexpn` says the `:h` expansion modifier works like the `dirname` tool). Then, assuming you have not unset the MUTLIOS option, the output of `:` (a command that produces no output) is appended to the files.

Comment: thank you for zshexpn i think this was the missing ingredient i needed. while i use zsh i mostly 'know' bash and fill in what I don't with bash/zsh knowledge as it is still  simplest  to find shell scripting info about bash via web search.